# Python Regex and Pandas

Tags: python, regex

I have a text in html, which later I want to convert into a pandas dataframe.

I have a text that looks like so:

```
<tr>
   <td -some attributes- >Val1</td>
   <td -some attributes- >Val2</td>
   <td -some attributes- >Val3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td -some attributes- >Val4</td>
   <td -some attributes- >Val5</td>
   <td -some attributes- >Val6</td>
</tr>
```

and I have the regex: `<td.*>(.*)</td>` but it doesn't catches all the values, it cathces almost all the text...

after I ctach all, I put it in a dataframe.

so why this regex doesn't catch the values as it should?

Comment: I'd recommend beautifulsoup instead of regex https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4 ..... also show the actual code you tried to use

Comment: It could be that you look at each row, one at a time and that a value spans multiple rows, or something completely different. I second the previous comment. Use beautifulsoup to parse html.

Comment: Give some example of tags that it does not catch.

Comment: Your RegEx `<td.*>(.*)</td>` is greedy (see (documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) ). So it captures more than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> You can try like this instead of REGEX - just an opinion

```
import pandas as pd
movies_table = pd.read_html("xxx.y.com")
movies = movies_table[0] // select the correct table from the tables array.
```

I got this working with me. Below I have attached a sample for use.

[image: Reading directly table data as DataFrame]

Answer (score 0):

If you (really) want to use a RegEx, you can do as follow:

```
content = """\
<tr>
   <td -some attributes- >Val1</td>
   <td -some attributes- >Val2</td>
   <td -some attributes- >Val3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td -some attributes- >Val4</td>
   <td -some attributes- >Val5</td>
   <td -some attributes- >Val6</td>
</tr>"""

import re

td_regex = re.compile(r"<td[^>]+>"  # <td> tag
                      r"((?:(?!</td>).)+)")  # <td> content

print(td_regex.findall(content))
```

You'll get:

```
['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val4', 'Val5', 'Val6']
```